# Network path not found while joining client to domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, backup, domain

1. I am using Windows server 2008r2 and it has AD, DHCP and DNS. When I tried to join clients to our domain, it worked well for almost 5 years. But on monday it refused to join. The error message was "Network path not found" and no other error codes. What shall I do?
2. The second one is, I have a backup server which is Windows 2012. How do I recover or migrate my backup data in to main sever Win2008?

**I will be very thankful & at your service if you help me out, its a mater of life.**

Comment: Did you tried https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/285182 ?

Comment: it started to happen only in this week,befor that every thing is perfect and know i have tryed in 3 computers with windows 7 ultimate x64 but none of them are working.

Comment: Is your AD service, DHCP service and DNS service running on the server ? can the client ping the server ? Where did you find your error (client/server side) ?

Comment: yes all of them are on one server and all client computers can ping correctly, i found this error message form client side

Comment: I mean are the services actually running ? maybe an error occured will service was running and make them stop... Any log server side on the date your trouble started ?

Comment: Yes all of them are running and I have restarted DNS role if it helps but no luck. Does it associate with loopback IP problem?

Comment: post an `ipconfig /all` output from both the server and a client with the problem

Comment: There is not even a single problem indication on the ping.
 What kind of IP do you give for your main DNS server as a primary and alternate?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay but i find a solution for this problem.

1. press window + R
2. write msconfig and press enter
3. go to boot tab and select "safe boot" and check "Network"
4. press OK and restart
5. now go to system property >change>check Domain >domain name>admin
   name & password .
6. before restarting repeat 1 & 2 and change "selective startup" into "Normal startup" and restart.

you  are DONE!

Answer (score -1):

We had the same issue so I went to dc and netdom query pdc it showed me server holding pdc role is down. so resting machine password fixed the issue.

It can also be bcoz of antivirus or time difference issue.or may be you need to add dns of dc on workstation.